# Kendo UI grid page size in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm relatively new to using Kendo UI. I've got grids on multiple pages that have page size dropdowns. There is a value that I send to it from the controller for the default page size, but if a user changes it on one of these pages, I'd like that value to be used for the default on any other grid. I was thinking that if I could store that info in session, that could work, but I'm not sure how to get that value into there from the client side when that value is changed. Does anybody out there know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about handling the onchange event of the page-size drop downs to call an action on the controller to set the session variable? You can make the call through a jquery post.

Comment: Thanks! A request was actually made to change the location of the dropdown, so I ended up creating a separate dropdown that I was able to bind to easier, and that worked perfectly.